# How to redirect url using ajax and Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying redirect URL on data submit. Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
        $error = array();

        $user_id=$_SESSION['email'];
        $apply_id=$_SESSION['id'];      

        $purpose_amount=$_POST['purpose_amount'];
        $amount=$_POST['amount'];
        $cheque_name=$_POST['cheque_name'];

        if(empty($amount)){
            $error[] =  "Please Enter Expected Amount";
        }
        elseif(empty($cheque_name)){
            $error[] =  "Please Enter Issue Cheque in Favour of";
        }
        if (count($error)) {
            echo "<i class='fa fa-exclamation'> ";
            echo implode('<br>', $error);
            echo "</i>";
        }
        else{
            $result=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE education SET amount='$amount', cheque_name='$cheque_name', purpose_amount='$purpose_amount', date='$date' WHERE id='$apply_id'")or die("Could not insert data: " .mysqli_error($conn));
                echo 1;         
        }
?>
```

And here is JQuery and AJAX code:

```
$('.btn_education_step5').click(function(){            
        var formdata=new FormData($('#education_step5')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url:'includes/backend_education_amount.php',
            method: "POST",
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data : formdata,
            success:function(answer_from_actionpage){               
                if(answer_from_actionpage == 1){                    
                  Redirect url code??????
                }else{
                    $('.error').html(answer_from_actionpage);
                }
            }
        })
});
```

When my data is submitted I want to redirect URL like this `abc.php?id=$user_id`
What can I do in `success:function()` to redirect URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax form redirect after submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31552474/ajax-form-redirect-after-submit)

Comment: try this `window.location = "page_name.php";`

Comment: you may use this `window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com"; `

Comment: my ulr like this: abc.php?id=$user_id

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect current page to any url by using following JavaScript script

```
window.location.href = "http://www.example.com";
```

So in your if statement use above script for redirection

```
if(answer_from_actionpage == 1){                    
        window.location.href = "http://www.example.com"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location = '';`

As you said your url like this `abc.php?id=$user_id`.

so first of all you save your `$user_id` in *JavaScript variable*.

```
 var user_id = '<?php echo $user_id; ?>';
```

then use the below line to redirect.

```
window.location = 'abc.php?id='+user_id;
```

Comment: After put your code redirect page show url like this abc.php?id=<?php echo $user_id; ?>

Comment: or before this line `window.location = 'abc.php?id='+user_id;` add this line `alert(user_id);` and check what is in alert?